# Stimulus Reflex drop down with selectize.js

Tags: ruby-on-rails-6, selectize.js, stimulus-reflex

I have a search form for an index page following the [tabular demo](https://expo.stimulusreflex.com/demos/tabular). It works perfectly. The list I have that I want to filter by is quite long and I wanted to make it searchable so I added [selectize.js](https://github.com/selectize/selectize.js), that piece also works just fine.

The problem is they don't work together. After selecting an item now it doesn't fire off the call to `TabularReflex#search` to filter the results.

```rb
#app/views/foo.index.html

<%= form_with scope: :search, url: '/search', html: { "data-reflex" =>"debounced:change->TabularReflex#search"} do |f| %>
  <%= f.select :foo, options_for_select(@search.foo), {include_blank: 'Select a Foo'}, {class: 'selectize'} %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: `debounced:div->TabularReflex#search` that `div` should probably be `change`

Comment: @RolandStuder good catch, I had it as `input` but was changing it around in the code to try and get it to work. `change` still does't work with `selectize` though.

Comment: Hard to tell without creating our own example, but StimulusReflex and jquery don't always play nice together, because jquery does special things with events and events listeneres that are not native and can lead to problems. I recomend to look for an alternative to selectize that does not depend on jquery and try with that.